# Trying to get a div to float right- jsfiddle included

Tags: css

I use a div to create a frame around an image. I am trying to get the div and it's containing image to float to the right so that the surrounding paragraphs will wrap around it.

Link to jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0vnfngws/

Styles:

```
.imgframe {
    margin: 12px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px;
    border: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
    background: #f7f7f7;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 0 #e5e5e5;
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 0 #e5e5e5;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 0 #e5e5e5;
}
.imgframe img {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 8px;
}
.floatright { 
    float: right;
}
```

HTML:

```
<p>This is some text here. I want the paragraph to wrap around the image, not to be positioned above and below it.</p>

<div class="imgframe"> <img src="http://www.hdicon.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/Firefox_2004_2.png" alt="#" class="floatright" /> </div>

<p>This is some more text here. I want the paragraph to wrap around the image, not to be positioned above and below it.</p>
```

Comment: simple `.imgframe{float:right;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is add `float: right;` to your `.imgframe`.

```
.imgframe {
    float: right;
    margin: 12px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
    padding: 8px;
    border: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
    background: #f7f7f7;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 0 #e5e5e5;
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 0 #e5e5e5;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 0 #e5e5e5;
}
```

See the [updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0vnfngws/4/).

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. Swap the order of the first *p* tag and the *div* tag
2. Move the *floatright* class from the img tag into the div tag

Answer (score 0):

Put the class on the containing div, not on the img tag.  You are floating the image within the containing div.